# How to create custom calendar with event management?

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

My Requirement:-
I am trying to make an app which have only calendar functionality, when user opens the app, calendar opens same like Google calendar. I receive events from web service and i have to show those events according to the date in calendar. Now if their is any event on any date than their should be a color block for event time, and if multiple events are there, than we have to show multiple color blocks each for one events.

I am here for a good piece of advice. Can i do this by default libraries or API's? because I have read android API's [`Calendar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html), [`CalendarView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html), [`calendar-provider`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html), [`CalendarContract`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html).  But no one tells that how can we show events in your own calendar.

So I am trying it with custom calendar. I am able to create custom calendar by using `Gridview`.

[image: Image of calendar I have now].

I want it to look like this with events

[image: Calendar Image with Events].

BTW My minimum Android support is android v4.0

Comment: What do you expect from "any API to make a custom calendar", question is really hard to understand

Comment: An custom calendar where user can manage his events

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a question, but more of a rant.

Comment: @CommonsWare, sorry i am newbie here, I don't know much details, i just need help to make a custom calendar with events functionality, if you find my question rant then You can edit my question and make it more specific.

Comment: "i just need help to make a csutom calendar with events functionality" -- the problem is that out of ~8 billion people on the planet, there is at most one person who knows what you mean by this. Rather than whining about how all these other sites did not do your work for you, you might consider explaining, **completely and precisely**, what you mean by "a csutom calendar with events functionality".

Comment: ok, i want to make a calendar like google calendar, but in the grids where it shows dates and a color if there is any event, i want event details also on that date.

Comment: @CommonsWare please check update question now.

Answer (score 10):

> Can i do this by default libraries or API's?

No. `CalendarView` is more of an alternative date picker than `DatePicker`.

[`ExtendedCalendarView`](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/04/extendedcalendarview/) looks like it is more in line with what you are seeking.

Comment: or this : http://www.androidviews.net/2013/03/timessquare-for-android/

Comment: @HelmiB: Actually, that is more like `CalendarView` -- it is designed for picking dates, not showing events on a calendar.

Comment: yes i find ExtendedCalendarView more suitable for my requirement. upvoted for now, will accept it for sure if it solves my problem :)

Comment: Just to update with with the correct information if other people come across this. That version of the library `ExtendedCalendarView` has been renames to GoogleCalendarView and I started fresh with the ExtendedCalendarView because the GoogleCalendarView has a lot a problems. The new one can be found here https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView