# Android availability Calendar view

Tags: android, mysql, calendar

I want to make calendar view for apartment availability app. 
My idea is to get from MySQL database ranges of dates(unavailable dates)  and display them in calendar view.
My calendar view should have 3 different styles:

1. available dates
2. unavailable (used) dates
3. arrival/ departure (start or finish of data ranges from MySQL)

Also when use clicks on some of that ranges from MySQL new forms shows.

Could someone give me some hint where to start?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644575/custom-calendar-with-events-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you can start from here: https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView